# plugin ng2-file-upload: how to return the response

Tags: angular

Angular2:

I have a **component** and a **service**. Component calls service and it must return the response. The problem is that I don't know how to return the response. My **component** is like:

```
uploadFile(docId: any) {
        let pos = this.uploader.queue.length-1;
        //We pick the last one
        this._uplService.uploadDoc(this.uploader.queue[pos], docId, this.innerText)
    }
```

The **service** does this thing:

```
uploadDoc(file: FileItem, docId : any, title: String){
    let headers = this._httpWrapper.genetareAuthHeader("path", "POST");
    let user = this._userService.getUser();

    file.url = user.config.apiUrl+"path?options="+user.options;
    file.upload();
    file.onSuccess = function(response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders) {
      console.log(response);
    }
    file.onError = function(response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders) {
      console.error(response);
    }
```

My problem is to return **response** and **error** from the service to the component. I tried to do an observable from promise, from response etc. but observables are really hard and all the times I tried, 'uploadDoc' returned a **function** (file.onSuccess or file.onError) not the **value** returned by the function (response).

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43517846/5419266

Comment: I didn't remember if I fixed that in some way, but I don't think that link helps. I'll explain. I had the response on 'service' (lines 'file.onError' and 'file.onSucces') but from there I have to pass the result to the controller (where there is the function 'uploadFile') but I don't know how to pass information from service to controller.