# How to return response with ng2-file-upload

Tags: angular, ng2-file-upload

I am using ng2-file-upload in angular 4. Is there any way to return custom data from server? How would we access it in ts file?

Answer (score 38):

You should be using uploader onSuccessItem and onErrorItem callbacks:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FileUploader, FileItem, ParsedResponseHeaders} from "ng2-file-upload";

@Component({
    selector: 'upload-file',
    template: `
    <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader">    
    `,
})
export class UploadFileComponent {
    uploader:FileUploader;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.uploader = new FileUploader({
            url: 'http://url.to/upload',
            headers: [{name:'Accept', value:'application/json'}],
            autoUpload: true,
        });
        this.uploader.onErrorItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onErrorItem(item, response, status, headers);
        this.uploader.onSuccessItem = (item, response, status, headers) => this.onSuccessItem(item, response, status, headers);
    }

    onSuccessItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
        let data = JSON.parse(response); //success server response
    }

    onErrorItem(item: FileItem, response: string, status: number, headers: ParsedResponseHeaders): any {
        let error = JSON.parse(response); //error server response
    }
}
```

Comment: @TanviShah Please accept this answer if you find it correct

Comment: This works, but i have one more question, how to handle when user second time upload some file, after first time onSuccessItem function never calls again ?